# Form information not being 'seen' by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, css, xhtml

I've made a new log in / register template which uses CSS3 and HTML, yet I had a working form, but very basic, before this. So I decided to make another 'form' which should look like this:
[http://www.script-tutorials.com/css 3-modal-popups/](http://www.script-tutorials.com/css%203-modal-popups/)

Now, I use this form to handle my registration:

```
<!-- Popup Form #2 -->
    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="join_form"></a>
    <div class="popup">
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <p>
        Please enter your details here.
      </p>
      <div>
   <form action="register.php" action="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Max 32 characters" name="username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" name="lastname" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="example@hotmail.com" name="email" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Join the Community" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </form>
```

Yet when I test this form, it will say the data is stored (My register.php file comes with a if-statement), yet it displays nothing. (No username, (password still gets hashed / stored, though I'm not sure if it's really handling it), last name and e-mail.

I've checked and double checked the 'name' attributes' value in the register.php file. And those are correct.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code too, please?

Comment: There is no need to. The problem has been solved.
I just have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer that has been provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you are accessing your form values using `$_POST`.  The problem is that in your form tag you are setting `action` twice, one of which is correct i.e. `action="register.php"` and the other `action="post"` is incorrect.

Try:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Oh gosh.. how can I be that stupid?
Thanks a lot!!

Though I still have to wait 11 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: It happens sometimes after a long day! :)

Comment: I guess so, but still.. :)

Answer (score 0):

and remember to enclose variables in quotes, for example

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$bar = $_POST['bar'];

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO my_table (foo, bar) VALUES ('$foo', '$bar');";
```

Comment: I know, there are no troubles in my register.php file. Since I've used it before I had the new login form.
The problem has been solved.

Thanks though, for your input.